# how to create C# code file into .dll file

Tags: dll

I wanted to create .dll file from current project of ASP.NET  **C#** I want to create the .dll file for that class and I don't want classes in it I just wanted .dll file to use in it 
thank you....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new project as class liabrary in your current project and add that class into it.
then build the solution. now you can add reference to your main project.my suggession is add project reference so that every time you build that will create new updated dll and will reflect in your current project.

Comment: I don't want any class in my project just wanted the build dll's that classes and after that I want to use them as refrence so that no one can see the code and can perform as my current classes were working

Comment: so instead of adding project in current project. create new c# class liabrary project.add class in that project. Build project . go to bin folder. copy the dll and paste in your current project bin and reference in current page.